# Google Drive Api Error with client token

Tags: google-drive

I have created a project and service account and enabled the google API for my email.

I added that service account and oath details to google library.

When I try to upload a video or image to google drive I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method." } '

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First authorize your api on google Admin. Go to the security -> advanced setting-> manage api client access. Here you will find authorize api clients. Where you will enter client name and api scope and click authorize after click authorize. After authorization you issue will be resolved.